# Bridging issue when we use Objective-c properties in swift classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I'm doing an iPad app using swift. But I have some classes which are already developed in objective-c. Now the problem is even after I'm importing objective-c class in bridging header it is showing error in swift file where I need to use objective c variables. I'm showing the **project structure** and bridging header's content along with the error below.

[image]

the folder structure is like

[image]

and the **bridging header's** content is

```
#import "SObjectData.h"
#import "SObjectDataSpec.h"
#import "SObjectData+internal.h"
```

the following is **CallSObjectData.swift** where i'm actually getting issue.there might be a small mistake.

If the I set

> swift compiler -  code generation

as follows

[image]

I'm getting the following issue.

[image]

If the I set

> swift compiler -  code generation

as follows

[image]

It is giving me the **file doesn't exist** error

Please help me finding the bug. thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure click on project file in left pane file explorer. Target -> Build Settings -> under field Swift Compiler - Code Generation make sure your bridging file path is correct.

Comment: thanks @NSGangster. +1
provide as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure click on project file in left pane file explorer. Target -> Build Settings -> under field Swift Compiler - Code Generation make sure your bridging file path is correct.

Comment: Hey @NSGangster
now I'm getting bridge file not found error. Please help me